# Verifying Bitcoin Knots download using GPG4Win

Tags: pgp, bitcoin, gpg4win

I'm trying to install [Bitcoin Knots](https://bitcoinknots.org/), but the process of key validation is new to me.
What I did:

- Downloaded https://gpg4win.org/get-gpg4win.html and ran Kleopatra
- Download Bitcoin Knots for Windows https://bitcoinknots.org/
- Downloaded Signature File: https://bitcoinknots.org/files/26.x/26.1.knots20240325/SHA256SUMS.asc
- Downloaded achow101.gpg from https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/tree/main/builder-keys
- Imported Public Keys into Kleopatra: "File" > "Import Certificates" imported achow101.gpg
- In Kleopatra: "File" > "Decrypt/Verify Files"
- Selected SHA256SUMS.asc downloaded
- Then select bitcoin-26.1.knots20240325-win64-setup-unsigned.exe

I get error:
Verified ‘bitcoin-26.1.knots20240325-win64-setup-unsigned.exe’ with ‘SHA256SUMS.asc’:
The data could not be verified.

What am I doing wrong?